# How to set resolution for a conversion from psd pdf using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm setting the density to 300 and resize to 1024x780 but the image in the pdf is so small when I view the pdf at 100%. How can I have the desired size when the pdf is viewed at 100%.

The imagemagick string is as follows:

```
"convert facebook2.psd[0] -resize 1024x780 -quality 100 -density 600 psdToPdf.pdf"
```

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16 x64

Please let me know if you need any information regarding the test. To see the issue with the pdf, please use the link [here](https://ibb.co/kaarcU)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The higher density is reducing the parts-per-inch ratio. Try updating with `-density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -page 1024x780`. Does that get you closer to what your expecting?

Comment: Try setting the density before reading the input PDF, like "convert -density 600 input.pdf ..."

Comment: @emcconville, setting the density as 72 solved my problem. Thank you